# Integrate Fancy Product Designer in my Next.js app

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, e-commerce

I am trying to integrate FancyProductDesigner into Nextjs. But unfortunately it is not working as it should. anyone integrate or have an idea how to integrate in Next.js

```
"use client"
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import FancyProductDesigner from "./dist/js/FancyProductDesigner.min.js"

const index = () => {
  let fpd // Declare fpd in a scope accessible to both functions

  useEffect(() => {
    const appOptions = {
      // Define your app options here...
    };

    fpd = new FancyProductDesigner(
      document.getElementById("fpd-target"),
      appOptions
    )
  }, []) // Empty dependency array ensures this effect runs once when the component mounts

  const save = () => {
    if (fpd) {
      fpd.getProductDataURL(function (dataURL) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(dataURL))
        console.log(dataURL)
        // You can make API calls or other actions here
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div
        id="fpd-target"
        className="fpd-sidebar fpd-shadow-2 fpd-views-inside-right"
      >
        <button onClick={save}>Save</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default index
```

I try to emded in my Next.js app but it is not working